# Nomenclature: does this coset space have a name?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, terminology

in my work I tripped on a specific coset space and before starting thinking about it by myself, I wanted to check the literature.  However, I do not know if the object has a name (which makes difficult googling it...).  In the set of "similar questions" proposed by MO I did not see anything similar.

Therefore, I am asking you if you if this has a name and maybe some references.

The coset space I am talking about is $SO(2)^N/\Gamma_N$ where

$$
\Gamma_N = \{ x \in \{-I, I\}^N \subset SO(2)^N : \prod_i x_i = I \} 
$$ 
where $I$ is, obviously, the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. In other words, every element of $\Gamma_N$ has an even number of entry equal to $-I$.

Do $SO(2)^N/\Gamma_N$  or $\Gamma_N$ have a name?

Comment: Maybe ${\rm SO}(2)^N/\Gamma_N$  does not have a name, and maybe you cannot find much in the literature. It is a topological torus of dimension N (with an  action of the permutation group $S_N$).